# Ways to persist partially updated object with hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am using Spring 3 and Hibernate 4 to build my project.

My question is that for example, a User object has five fields, id, name, password, school and address. I only give the user the right to update/edit his school and/or address. When the user first access the edit page via GET,I want to populate the field with the user's existing information.

Once submit button is clicked, I want to change the corresponding updated fields in my database via hibernate.

Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/edit/{userId}", method="RequestMethod.GET")
public String toEdit(Model model,@PathVariable int userId){
    User user = userService.get(userId);
    model.addAttribute("command",user);
    return "/edit";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/save", method="RequestMethod.POST")
public String toSave(Model model){
    //how to implement this?
}
```

edit.jsp

```
<form:form action="/save" method="POST">
    <form:input path="school"/>
    <form:input path="address"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form:form>
```

My thought is that if I can put those fields that are not updated as hidden field in the edit.jsp page so that when the User object rebinds(when the form is submitted), I could still capture the user's id, name and password information.

The pitfall of my approach is obvious. First, password as hidden field is never the way to go. Second, it adds unnecessary information on the edit.jsp page.

My second thought is that I could only put the user id as hidden field in the edit.jsp and when the form is submitted, I could use `User user = userService.get(command.id)`  to get the corresponding user object and set the fields (e.g. school or address) to those newly entered ones by something like `user.setSchool(command.getSchool())`. After all of these, I can update the user object. This approach is kinda of troublesome, because if I got a lot of fields to update, there is gonna be a lot of code.

Is there a better way to do this? (I am sure there must be one) I am very new to Spring and Hibernate, so if I am missing something very obvious, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ["dynamic-update"](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-class) only modified fields will be updated.
You may ues the [`@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-entity) to mark your entity for dynamic updates.

```
@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(
        selectBeforeUpdate = true,
        dynamicInsert = true, dynamicUpdate = true)
public class User { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your method but it does not seem to do what I expected. In my understanding,dynamic update means that only those modified fields will be updated in the database. However, when I rebind the values after update, I actually lost the value of name/password because they do not exist in the form. Do you have any idea about how to cope with that? Thanks.

Comment: As long as a unique identifier of the User is available there is no need to have all fields within the html form. If the user submits the form you fetch the User Object identified by the unique identifier from the database and update the fields with the values from the form. The User Identifier may be the Username (natural key) the database id (surrogate key) and may be stored within the HTTP Sesssion. It's also possible to store the whole (detached) User Object within the HttpSession and reconnect it whith the Hibernate Session on Form Submit. The principle is very similar to the one above.